# How to use initial value when composing functions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, composition, ramda.js

How does one best form a composition of functions when one has to conserve an initial value passed in to the first function and use it part of the way through the pipeline?

As an example let's say I want to create a composition of functions that gets a fee based on the amount passed in, adds it to the the amount, converts to cents and formats the result as a string (using Ramda):

```
getTotalAsStr = R.compose(
  formatDollars
  R.divide(100),
  addFee
  getFee
);
```

I'd call it like this: `getTotalAsStr(500)`. I pass in the amount in cents, calculate the fee based on the amount and add the fee to the amount.

But `getFee` returns the fee. `addFee` needs the original amount to add the fee to. I was thinking currying, but that's for when you have a non-variable parameter.

I could create a function that receives the amount and totals the amount and fee and passes that on to `divide(100)` and use that in the composition, or I could have `getFee` return an object with the original amount and the fee, then have `addFee` total the two values, but that's ugly and makes `addFee` awkward.

Is there a way to elegantly do what I want using one composition?

Comment: There's a current discussion about how to make such things more palatable in single pipelines:  https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/2930#issuecomment-562218926

Comment: Also, if `addFee` is curried (e.g., `const addFee = (amount) => (fee) => amount + fee` -- `R.add` would work.), then this should work: `compose (formatDollars, divide(100), chain(addFee, getFee))`, because `chain(f, g) //~> (x) => f (g(x), x)`..